# Why can't I buy some of the gear that should be available to me in Honor Hold?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, I've reached the "Honored" level of reputation with Honor Hold. I decided to check online what kind of gear I should be able to buy because of that and I've noticed that some of the gear listed [here](http://www.wowpedia.org/Honor_Hold#Rewards) doesn't even appear in the list of things I can buy from the logistics officer. In my case specifically the Savage Plate Helm.

Why doesn't it even appear? Has this item been removed or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me guess, you're playing as a Paladin or a Death Knight, aren't you?

The [Savage Plate Battlegear](http://www.wowhead.com/itemset=750) is a PVP set for **Warriors**, introduced late in the Burning Crusade expansion. The items were available from reputation vendors as entry level PVP gear, and were class restricted, with class specific set bonuses. As with most PVP and PVE set pieces, only those items wearable by your class are visible on the vendors that sell them. As a Death Knight for instance, you would never see any pieces of [Valorous Frostfire](http://www.wowhead.com/itemset=-33) gear being sold by [Paldesse](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=28995) either.

If you're playing a Paladin, the similar sets available to you are the [Crusader's Scaled](http://www.wowhead.com/itemset=752) or [Crusader's Ornamented](http://www.wowhead.com/itemset=751) battlegear. If you're playing a Death Knight, I'm sorry to say that you're out of luck -  DK's were introduced in Wrath of the Lich King, and Burning Crusade content did not receive many updates to accommodate them -  especially not updates to endgame PVP gear that isn't particularly good when compared to greens available in new Wrath zones anyway.